# How do I overwrite console output?

Tags: rust, console

Is there a way to overwrite console output using Rust instead of simply appending?

An example would be printing progress as a percentage; I would rather overwrite the line than print a new line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consoles are usually controlled by printing out "control characters", but what they are depends on the platform and terminal type. You probably don't want to reinvent the wheel to do this.

You can use the [crossterm crate](https://crates.io/crates/crossterm) to get this kind of console control. A simple example is:

```rust
use std::{thread, time};
use std::io::{Write, stdout};
use crossterm::{QueueableCommand, cursor, terminal, ExecutableCommand};

fn main() {
    let mut stdout = stdout();

    stdout.execute(cursor::Hide).unwrap();
    for i in (1..30).rev() {
        stdout.queue(cursor::SavePosition).unwrap();
        stdout.write_all(format!("{}: FOOBAR ", i).as_bytes()).unwrap();
        stdout.queue(cursor::RestorePosition).unwrap();
        stdout.flush().unwrap();
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));

        stdout.queue(cursor::RestorePosition).unwrap();
        stdout.queue(terminal::Clear(terminal::ClearType::FromCursorDown)).unwrap();
    }
    stdout.execute(cursor::Show).unwrap();

    println!("Done!");
}
```

Comment: Coming back to this after a while, notably this doesn't actually clear the console line it wrote, but simply writes something new on top. E.g. writing `started` then writing `done` will leave `doneted`. Is there a way to clear lines? (looking at `crossterm::terminal::Clear` right now, but without examples it's hard to understand)

Comment: It looks like to clear the current line you just queue a `terminal::Clear(ClearType::CurrentLine)`.

Comment: If you're trying to put together a more complex text GUI, then crossterm is possibly at the wrong level - you may be better off with TUI (https://github.com/fdehau/tui-rs)

Comment: `SavePosition`/`RestorePosition` did not work for me, but `MoveToPreviousLine(n)` did. Also this code has compiler warnings as none of the Results is handled.

Comment: @piegames did you add error handling to work out why the `SavePosition` / `RestorePosition` calls were not working for you? Just adding `.unwrap()` to each of the `queue` calls is probably enough to get some idea of why. (They certainly worked for me, and I suspect it may depend on your terminal capabilities / type.

Comment: Michael Anderson: No, I added the error handling because the whole code was yellow in the IDE. :D Besides, the code does not panic after having added the error "handling" so it's not that. It may be because I write more than one line, but as manually moving the cursor works fine as well I didn't bother investigating.

Answer (score 9):

For a lower-level approach, you can use the `\r` escape that will return the cursor to the beginning of the line and overwrite from there.

```rust
use std::{
    io::{stdout, Write},
    thread::sleep,
    time::Duration,
};

fn main() {
    let mut stdout = stdout();

    for i in 0..=100 {
        print!("\rProcessing {}%...", i);
        // or
        // stdout.write(format!("\rProcessing {}%...", i).as_bytes()).unwrap();

        stdout.flush().unwrap();
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(20));
    }
    println!();
}
```

You can also use a backspace character to move the cursor back one space.

```
const BACKSPACE: char = 8u8 as char;

print!("{}\rThis replaces the previous line", BACKSPACE);
```

#### Note:

This works best for simple incrementing values like this.
If you write `Hello, World!` then `\rbar` you will end up with `baro, World!`.
If you want to clear the output the best way would be to keep track of the number of characters you have written and overwrite them with spaces, or you could use a library that can give you the terminal size.